# Why doesn't the a+ mode work here?

Tags: io, d

According to the offcial D book:

> a+:   read and append access. 
>       if the file does not exist, it is created as empty
>       if the file already exists, its contents are preserved and the file is opened to be read from the beginning and written at the end.

But if I do the following, it does not read anything from the file:

```
import std.stdio;

void main() {
    File fh = File("/tmp/x.mail", "a+");
    string line;
    while((line = fh.readln()) !is null) {
        write(line);
    }
}
```

I am on OSX 10.9, compiler is ldc2.

Comment: works for me... are you sure the file actually exists and has contents?

Comment: Yes, it does have content. What OS do you use?

Comment: linux. What are you on?

Comment: ^According to the OP, he's on OSX 10.9. Just to confirm the possibility that this is indeed a a+ problem, could you use the "r" mode instead and see if it outputs anything ?

Comment: "r" mode works perfectly fine.

Comment: Is this a phobos bug?

Answer (score 4):

From [MacOS X documentation for fopen()](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/fopen.3.html):

`"a+"  Open for reading and writing.  The file is created if it does not exist.  The stream is positioned at the end of the file.  Subsequent writes to the file will always end up at the then current end of file, irrespective of any intervening fseek(3) or similar.`

I am quite sure Phobos uses fopen() behind the scenes on MacOS X to open that file, so the stream is positioned at the end. Try to call fseek() and then read.